# Sound attenuation when holes size less than wavelength

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, estimation

The actual problem is as follows. There is a gap between a transducer and its circular mounting collar that is about half the wavelength of the incoming sound. [image]

What I do not want is for the incoming wave to be reflected from the recessed surface - only the transducer face. Is there any relatively simple rule of thumb I can apply to estimate the amplitude of the reflected wave given the gap spacing d?

Comment: For clarification, do you mean Intensity of the reflected wave instead of *amplitude of the reflected wave?*

Comment: @Sathyam Yes, as in "how much is reflected". BTW, we are talking sine wave.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your diagram. It is labeled with both "Tx" and "Rx". Where is the sound coming from? What is the right hand arrow pointing at? What is the depth of the recessed collar below the face(?) of the transducer? What is the over all diameter of the tube relative to the incident wavelength? All unanswered questions...

Comment: @Floris Overall diameter >>wavelength. Depth still to be determined but at least 4x greater than wavelength. It is labeled Tx/Rx because it is a bidirectional transducer. The other arrow just points at empty space.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the characteristic impedance:

$$
Z_c = \frac{\rho_0 c_0}{S}
$$

where $S$ is the area of waveguide cross-section. Do that for the whole cross section and then for the reduced cross section (i.e. the transducer face only). The ratio of both should give you the first approximation of how large portion of power is reflected from the transducer.

However, this is only for short waveguides and/or low frequencies case. You have to model that in more details in case the waveguide is longer or the frequencies high. Give me a comment, if you want that maths as well.

**Engineering note:** Nevertheless, in my opinion, the best would be to make a smooth profile (use plasticine or so) so there won't be any discontinuities in $S$ and therefore any reflections before the transducer.

Comment: For any kind of wave guide, the amplitude of the wave will no longer be uniform so this becomes an approximation. As hinted in the answer, you can get better acoustic impedance matching using a _horn_ (like the old "speaker" of the mechanical gramophone).

Comment: I suspect I don't want impedance matching. I just do not want significant reflections from any point below the transducer surface.

Comment: But that's exactly what impedance matching would do for you. You just don't have to be extra precise in construction. Basically: *avoid the discontinuities in continuity equation domain*.